# term(s) to search user comment html styler scripts

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, user-input

I couldn't find the correct term(s) to search & read about the scripts which are used to allow the user to add some html tags capability while commenting or blogging. For example we can use  B, *I*, hyperlink, list etc capabilities while commenting on StackOverflow

which term(s) should I use to search the related scripts?
best regards

Comment: @DannyBeckett can you write your comment as an answer please; then let me accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BBCode or WYSIWYG will probably yield some results.

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) is a great pre-made option.